# Cmake link library with different arguments

Tags: cmake

I use `cmake-3.15.3` for generation and then build executables using `ninja`.

I have 2 executables (2 different `CMakeLists.txt`) that depend on the same library (one more `CMakeLists.txt`), that I link to them using `target_link_libraries` in both executables.

This library has custom command `add_custom_command` that invokes custom python script.

**Problem:**
I want to pass different arguments to this custom command python script from different executables. Is it possible?

common_lib:

```
CMakeLists.txt
add_library(common_lib)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/input_file.c
  COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/info_generate.py
    -d ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    -r ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    -o input_file.c ${foobarBAZ}
  DEPENDS ${MR_FILES} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/info_generate.py
  COMMENT Generating input_file.c
)
```

exec1:

```
CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(exec1)

target_link_libraries(exec1
common_lib)
```

exec2:

```
CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(exec2)

target_link_libraries(exec2
common_lib)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass different arguments to this custom command python script from different executables.

Do not write spaghetti code - the library users should have no effect on the library itself. The library is self-contained and the library depended should not modify the library itself.

> Is it possible?

Create a function that would create the library:

```
cmake_include_guard()
function(add_mycommonlib_library target)
    add_custom_command(
       OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/input_file.c
       COMMAND .... ${ARGV}
    )
    add_library(${target} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/input_file.c)
endfunction()
```

and then you would:

```
# exec1 CMakeLists.txt
include(../gen_common_lib.cmake)
add_mycommonlib_library(exec1_common_lib --some-argument)
add_executable(exec1)
target_link_libraries(exec1 exec1_common_lib)
```

Comment: Got it. So it will look like ugly hack in this case.  Need to think how to not to do this at all...
but thanks anyway.

Comment: I think the best solution here will be split one common library onto two libs and link a necessary one in each executable.

Comment: Looks nice to me. Research how other projects handle such cases: I know about cuda or zephyr.